# Enterprise App taking longer to start

Tags: ios, xcode, performance, enterprise

I'm currently experiencing some weird behaviour with the same codebase just being signed with different certificates:

```
1) Bundle identifier: com.mycompany.A, Normal App-Store Distribution certificate 

2) Bundle identifier: com.mycompany.B, Enterprise Distribution certificate
```

Like stated above both apps are having the exactly same code and assets compiled into them, the only thing that differs is the bundle identifier and the signing credentials used to archive them.

Weirdly, app A (1) takes ~40% of the time to start as compared to app B (2). Could this have anything to do with Apple more intensively checking Enterprise certificates? Or am I simply compiling it in a wrong way? Any ideas on how to mitigate this issue?

I already checked that I don't have any long running code in applicationDidFinishLaunching: which blocks the startup, it simply seems that its indeed iOS which takes so long to start the app and hand it over to my control.

Comment: What difference in seconds between the start up times are we talking about here?

Comment: Have you cleaned your project and removed Derived Data? (on xCode, Product >> Mantain Alt key >> Clean Build Folder)